# Is there a way to convert scalar values in an array to matplotlib colormap indices?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array that consists of a bunch of floats (e.g. [1202.21, -124.4, 23, ....]) that I've plotted with matplotlib using the colormap jet. Is there any way to get the indices of the jet scale (i.e. a single value 0-255) for each float in my array? I want to display some stats about the data but it only will make sense if the stats (mean, standard deviation, etc.) are within the 0-255 range.

I've tried returning the array used by matplotlib using get_array() but that doesn't seem to change the data.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this have anything to do with a colormap? Or do you just want to discretize your array into 256 bins and obtain the bin number?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'd like to know what each value maps to on the colormap, so that I can use this for my calculations

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) gives you the bin number for the data when put into bins. Here you have 256 bins and the last bin is closed. Hence,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])

N = 256
bins = np.linspace(a.min(), a.max(), N+1)
dig = np.digitize(a, bins)-1
dig[dig == N] = N-1 # map the last half-open interval back
print(dig)
```

Now verify that those are indeed the indices of the colormap:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cmap = plt.cm.jet
norm = plt.Normalize(a.min(), a.max())
colors1 = cmap(norm(a))

colors2 = cmap(dig)

assert(np.all(colors1 == colors2))
```